# Run test cases and on Success deploy - React JS App with Jenkins

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jenkins, continuous-integration

**I am trying to run test cases and deploy React-js app with Jenkins.**

I am able run react-js app locally after git push command, but after that second command **mocha** (command to run test cases) is **never executed**.

I want to deploy react-app to production if all test cases passes.

Below is my simple build script

> cd naviaget/to/package.json/file
>
> npm start
>
> mocha

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any build logs or steps to reproduce?

Comment: After npm start,
I am getting  
> react-scripts start
> Starting the development server

but mocha doesn't gets to execute ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if `npm start` is starting the development server, you shouldn't call it **before** running the scripts, because the server won't finish execution until it's closed. That's the reason `mocha` is never executed.

Normally in CI you first run your tests, and then if everything goes fine you deploy, run a server, whatever. These are normally two different steps: integration (running your test) and deployment (spinning up your server).

I'm not familiar with Jenkins but I'm pretty sure it should be easy to set it up like that:

1. Run the tests with mocha
2. If everything is fine, re-reploy

Comment: Yea, that makes sense. I am new to CI. Your answer helped a lot.